# How to open Visual Studio Code - Insiders from the command line in windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just like we open ***Visual Studio Code*** from command line by typing `code` (or `code .` to open VS Code with the shell's current working directory as the workspace folder).

What is the equivalent command we can use to open ***Visual Studio Code Insiders*** in the current directory?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

While installing **Visual Studio Code - Insiders** if you have added the path in the environment variable, then you can fire it from the command line by typing `code-insiders` right away.
The command is bit verbose/long and for which you may want to change it to `code-i` or `codi` for example. In order to rename the command, navigate to the path *C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin*  and there you will find a file with .cmd extension. Change the file name and it should work expectedly.

Comment: What is the Mac equivalent of this?

Answer (score 31):

This is what worked for me on Mac

- Open Visual Studio Code - Insiders.
- Open the Command Palette by pressing Shift+Cmd+P.
- Type "Shell Command: Install 'code-insiders' command in PATH" and select the option that appears.
- Restart terminal for the change to take effect.

Then `code-insiders` worked on the terminal.

Comment: You can also add `alias codi="code-insiders"` to `~/.zprofile` and use `codi .`

Answer (score 0):

When installing VS Code insiders, it was better to select the option "Add to Path". There'll be no clash between VS Code or Insider as it allows side by side installation and install paths/executable names are different.

However, here's how you can add Insiders to the path (sorry specific to windows).

1. open Profile

   notepad $PROFILE
2. add the following line and save the file
   $pathToAdd = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin"
   [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "$env:PATH;$pathToAdd", "User")

   ## reopen ps session to verify

   $env:Path | Select-String -Pattern "Microsoft VS Code Insiders"

And if you want the alias and that to persist, add the following to PowerShell profile

```
Set-Alias -Name codi -Value "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin\code-insiders.cmd"
```