# on macOS, how do I open Visual Studio Code Insiders from a shell?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

This has been [asked & answered for Windows already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62264109/241142), but the command given doesn't work for me on macOS, and the path is definitely different.

How can I open Visual Studio Code Insiders from a shell on macOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try opening VS Code Insiders and using [the command that adds it to the `PATH`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line).

Use the "`Shell Command: Install 'code-insiders' in PATH`" in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) of VS Code Insiders (the default keybinding for opening the command palette is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>.) and run it. Then restart your shells and try running `code-insiders`.

Answer (score 0):

I create a solution to solve this.

If `visual-studio-code-insiders-bin` is installed it creates an `alias` to reassign `code` as `code-insiders`, if not it uses the default alias for `code`.

1. Copy and paste it into your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file.

   ```bash
   # Check if code-insiders is installed
   if command -v code-insiders &> /dev/null; then
     alias code="code-insiders"
   fi

   # Define the code function
   function code() {
     command code "$@"
   }
   ```
2. Save your changes and refresh your file:

   Use `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` depending on your `$SHELL` or close and reopen the terminal/console.

Answer (score -1):

of courese, opening "vs code" from a shell on macOS is same as on widnwos;

maybe your "vs code" incorrectly install, so you can't open "vs code",
try to type "whereis code" on terminall.

if there isn't a output, you can add a alias "code = 'your vscode install path' "

Comment: it's not `code` for insiders. it's `code-insiders`.